# Can I put @ManagedBean in CDI scope?

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean

I'm using GlassFish 3.0.1. I want to know if I can use:

```
@ManagedBean
@ConversationScoped
```

Instead of `@Named`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ManagedBean` is a JSF annotation  while `@ConversationScoped` is a CDI annotation, I can't think of any valid scenario to combine them.

In general `@Named` will cover almost all you needs and it make your bean available to EL thus the JSF pages.

Comment: Yeah I always think so but I have a problem. I need to use  @FacesConverter(forClass=Class.class)   and use  `facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue` with CDI always have problem it always throw me a NULL pointer but with JSF it goes good.

Comment: Maybe you can use Deltaspike to enable injection into JSF artifacts